# How do I make a dropdown list within a tab? Angular5 with Material2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

So I've got this code which it is basically a navbar with tabs.

```
 <mat-tab-group>
 <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        main page 
    </ng-template>
    main page content
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" style="color:black;" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Options</button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="changeTab(0)">A</button>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="changeTab(1)">B</button>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="changeTab(2)">C</button>
       </mat-menu>
    </ng-template>
      <app-events></app-events>
 </mat-tab>
 <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        D
    </ng-template>
    <app-apply></app-apply>
 </mat-tab>
 <mat-tab >
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        E
    </ng-template>
    <app-faq></app-faq>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

One of my option tabs I wanted to be a drop down list tab, but with material2 if it is selected **immediately changes to that tab view** (Which I dont want), instead I want to just display menu options and then I wanted to condition the menu items to show the respective option component.

Here is an example. All Letters would have its on individual content page when selected, also main page. Is there a way to do this loading everything at ones with the mat-tab-group? All content is are static websites, that's why I want to load it ones, instead of creating routing.

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything in place which would indicate that the button contains dropdown items?

Comment: @Zze what you mean by in place?

Comment: As in, is there any sort of object or data which relates the options for your dropdown items with the parent button: for example: `{parent: 'menu', children: [{name: 'item1'}, {name: 'item2'}]}` etc. or is it just straight html based at the moment?

Comment: plain html for the moment. But I'd would try to identify which menu option was selected, so I can load the correct component content, that's why I improvised the ngIf's

Comment: Give me a bit and I will make an example how I would go about this. I'm not sure if you could achieve what you want without some sort of data relationship in your component.

Comment: @Zze thank you! I'm new to angular5 and material2 so any advice is more than appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi here I create an [online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evngxk)

Please check this is it solve your problem?

if it is then this is how it works:

> (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"

This creates a hook to go through the child event, not the parent event which activates the **menu** event from the code, not the **tab** event.

Also, paste the full code here:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 5">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
         <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">settings</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
          <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
        </mat-menu>
        </ng-template>
        No content  
      </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTab">
  <mat-tab label="Main Page">Main Page Content</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 5" disabled>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
         <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          <mat-icon color="warn" aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">more_vert</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="changeTab(2)">A</button>
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="changeTab(3)">B</button>
           <button mat-menu-item (click)="changeTab(4)">C</button>
        </mat-menu>
        </ng-template>
        No content  
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="A">A Content</mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="B">B Content</mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="C">C Content</mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="D">D Content</mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="E">E Content</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Component:**

```
selectedTab = 0;
  changeTab(tabIndex: number) {
    this.selectedTab = tabIndex;
  }
```

Comment: Interesting idea, haven't played enough with it. But it doesn't work how I'm asking. For more perspective imagine 3 tabs. One of them is a dropwdown that has three different page views it can load. And playing between the tabs or the dropdown menu shows different page views

Comment: Can you give me some pictorial representation of what you want? It helps me to understand your requirement with ease.

Comment: I update the demo code.. is it default behaviour you want? @Vesper

Comment: Thanks @AlokeT! Pressing the dropdown options should show there own respective views, not others.

Comment: Okay and I think you get the idea how to do it... Right? Enjoy Material design and follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would approach an issue like this. I apologize about the slightly rushed example. Here is a working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpfy1s

First I created an object which denotes the menu structure:

```
public menu: any = [{
      group: [
        {
          label: 'Parent1'
        },
        {
          label: 'Parent2' ,
          children: [
            {label: 'Item1'},
            {label: 'Item2'}
          ]
        }
      ]
  }];
```

And then I use this in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let menuItem of menu">
  <div *ngFor="let option of menuItem.group">
    <button *ngIf="!option.children"><a href="#">{{option.label}}</a></button>

    <button *ngIf="option.children" (click)="option.expanded = !option.expanded">{{option.label}}</button>
    <ul *ngIf="option.expanded">
      <li *ngFor="let child of option.children"><a href="#">{{child.label}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can see that the first button, knows that it does not have any children and therefor creates a button which contains an `<a>`. This would be where you trigger your tab change.

The second button, which does have children, does not render an `<a>` tag within the button and instead toggles the visibility  of the list instead.

Comment: thank you for your fast response! :) This works good without Material2. Where I was heading was using Material2 existing modules and making the tab with a dropwdown list not activate unless one of the children are pressed.

Comment: @Vesper This is a fairly generic approach, I am sure that you would be able to substitute in some material stuff. Honestly I have no experience with material, so that would be up to you. Hopefully it gives you the idea about how you can draw in a data object and use it in the menu.

Comment: Nop, really looking to stick with Material2 design modules. I adapted it with Material2 and played with it, but it didn't work. Looking for work arounds now.